# How to invoke method in a controller in a ruby file or rake script file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a method in a controller,

For example, I want call the `show` method in a script without opening the webpages.

Is it possible to do it ?

```
  def index
    @joseph_memos = JosephMemo.all
    @joseph_memo = JosephMemo.new
  end

  # GET /joseph_memos/1
  # GET /joseph_memos/1.json
  def show
    binding.pry
  end
```

Comment: what is your motive ? do you want to grab the html ? if so, why not just grab the data from URL ?

Comment: see my answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in Rails console, run `rails c` and type the following to test.

```
app.get('/joseph_memos/1')
output = app.html_document.root.to_s
```

But, if you also want to turn into rake task. Create the lib/tasks/actions.rake in your rails app. And add the following lines.

```
namespace :actions do
desc "test show action"
  task :show, [:id] => :environment do |task, args|
    app = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
    app.get("/joseph_memos/#{args[:id]}")
    puts app.html_document.root.to_s
  end
end
```

Then run, `rake actions:show[1]` to see the result.

Here is the result that works (that is, `bundle exec rake "actions:show[1]"` on zsh)

```
$bundle exec rake "actions:show[1]"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/joseph_memos.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/joseph_memos.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="lZqYRkVfhZUhMK8EQIRsdoX2l4IpTPPhHKB44DSaq7s=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<p id="notice"></p>

<a href="/joseph_memos/1/edit">Edit</a> |
<a href="/joseph_memos">Back</a>


</body>
</html>
```

More examples: https://github.com/henrik/remit/blob/master/lib/tasks/dev_events.rake

Hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's very much possible but implementing it won't be worth it.  An alternative solution would be to create a service class that you can call in the show action and you should also be able to use the same class outside of the controller.

```
def show
  MyShowActionHandler.new(params).do_something
end

class MyShowActionHandler
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end
end
```

Then just call `MyShowActionHandler` in a script and it should work as long as you load the rails environment.